How to setup Freemium Pricing Model Limits?
We are currently offering an integration app on Salesforce AppExchange and are exploring different pricing models. Specifically, we are interested in setting up a freemium pricing structure, where users can access certain features for free and upgrade to premium features via paid tiers.
However, we are unable to find any doc on how to control the limits of usage for the freemium tier and where these limits can be monitored or adjusted.
Could you please guide us on the best practices or steps required to implement this model within the AppExchange framework? Any tips on managing user upgrades, licensing, and trial periods would also be appreciated.

You can utilise the Feature Management App (FMA) functionality to manage these kind of pricing and feature access structures.
Within this, you can use Feature Parameters, which enable you to create different settings within your Managed Package that can be used to control access to features. You can either push parameter values from your License Management Org (LMO) to subscribers, which can be referenced in your package to toggle access, or have values pushed to your LMO from the subscriber, for tracking usage statistics for example.
When using LMO-to-Subscriber Feature Parameters, you can use the following to check the values and enable or disable features:
System.FeatureManagement.checkPackageBooleanValue('YourBooleanFeatureParameter');
System.FeatureManagement.checkPackageDateValue('YourDateFeatureParameter');
System.FeatureManagement.checkPackageIntegerValue('YourIntegerFeatureParameter');

In your case, you'd be able to set up Feature Parameters to indicate whether a Subscriber has a specific tier, or use an Integer parameter to check if they are going to breach the number of requests they are entitled to under their pricing tier.
There's a useful guide to setting up Feature Parameters as well as some considerations and best practices available in the Help Docs here:
Manage Features in Second-Generation Managed Packages
Note this is the Second-Gen link, but I believe this capability is the same for both First and Second Generation Managed Packages.

But how to set number of users limit? Or how to set API limit per month? do we need to run schedule job to reset month limit?

You can use the License Management App for the number of licensed users in the subscriber org https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/lma_intro.htm. For monthly limits, then yes you'd want to include a job that will reset a Subscriber-to-LMO parameter to pass that information back to your LMO org.
